# Is it possible to get suggested routes from google maps in android2.2 application?

Tags: android, google-maps, directions

I am using the following url to get driving directions from google maps.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=location1&daddr=location2&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml
```

I am getting only one route in my KML file. But when we searched same locations in web-browser it will show **suggested routes**.

In order to get all routes available as output, is there **any other parameter to add in URL**.

**I found some answers as use google directions API for JavaScript with &alternatives=true** Is it suitable for android ?? or any other solutions ??

**Don't comment if URL have any mistakes, i used correct one in my application.**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The answer does not address the question directly, but here it is:

I'd suggest using [The Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) and JSON output as far as

1) this API is better documented,

2) the parsing of JSON is much easier and

3) JSON consumes less network traffic because it stores data more effectively than XML (KML).

To solve your problem with Google Directions API you will just need to add `alternatives=true` [request parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters).

**However**, look through [this](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters) document. Perhaps, `start=n` parameter is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine these 2 urls:
[URL1](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=location1&destination=location2&mode=driving&alternatives=true&sensor=false)
[URL2](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=location1&daddr=location2&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml)
to get your best result

1. Request URL1 to get all paths you need
2. Request URL2 for each of your start_locations and end_locations from the URL1 above

But, this would make your program slow.:).

Comment: You can only use URL1 (Google Map WebService), and decode the polyline_data then get your path, I've just figured it out =D

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming it is looking for the shortest distance from point A to B along the roads. How about writing an algorithm based off of that?

Lets say from point A to B is 15 miles. There may be an alternate route that's will take you 5 miles more driving distance in the end. How about setting an adjustable range for the map to search for more than 15 miles based on the map? Maybe something that increments the distance until it matches up geographically, because usually, alternate routes will be longer.

To make it bit more complex, how about making a call to multiple routes?